# Algorithm - N Queens Stack Overflow

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write a backtracking code that will find the number of solutions in a NQueens problem. But I am getting stack overflows when I try to mark the diagonal grids where it is not safe to place a queen.

```
int dim;

private void recurseMark(int row, int col, boolean[][] board, boolean val) {
    if(row >= dim || col >= dim || row < 0 || col < 0) return;
    if(board[row][col]) return;
    System.out.println("Row " + row + " Col " + col);
    board[row][col] = val;
    recurseMark(row+1, col-1, board, val);
    recurseMark(row+1, col+1, board, val);
    recurseMark(row-1, col+1, board, val);
    recurseMark(row-1, col-1, board, val);
}

private void mark(int i, int k, boolean[][] board, boolean val) {
     for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        board[i][j] = val;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        board[j][k] = val;
    }
}

private int countQueens(int i, boolean[][] board) {
    int count = 0;

    if(i == dim) return 1;

    for(int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
        if(!board[i][k]) {
            board[i][k] = true;
            mark(i, k, board, true);
            System.out.println("Giving " + i + " " + k);
            recurseMark(i, k, board, true);
            count += countQueens(i+1, board);    
            recurseMark(i, k, board, false);
            mark(i, k, board, false);
        }
    }

    return count;
}


public int totalNQueens(int n) {
    dim = n;

    boolean[][] board = new boolean[n][n];

    return countQueens(0, board);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NQueens nq = new NQueens();
    System.out.println(nq.totalNQueens(2));
}
```

Any idea why it's overflowing for a small value of N?

Comment: I strongly recommend stepping through this with a debugger.  You will see the problem in seconds if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Because your method recurses infinitely.

If the board is 8x8, then for example `recurseMark(1, 1, board, false)` calls `recurseMark(2, 2, board, false)` which calls `recurseMark(1, 1, board, false)` which calls `recurseMark(2, 2, board, false)` which calls `recurseMark(1, 1, board, false)` which ...

Comment: Shouldn't the line `if(board[row][col]) return;` take care of that?

Comment: @user3666471 you're right... but not when `val == false`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when recurseMark is called with false.  Here is a correct recurseMark():

```
private void recurseMark(int row, int col, Boolean[][] board, Boolean val) {
    if(row >= dim || col >= dim || row < 0 || col < 0) return;
    if(board[row][col] != null) return;
    System.out.println("Row " + row + " Col " + col);
    board[row][col] = val;
    recurseMark(row+1, col-1, board, val);
    recurseMark(row+1, col+1, board, val);
    recurseMark(row-1, col+1, board, val);
    recurseMark(row-1, col-1, board, val);
}
```

What we have done here is to switch to a Boolean class rather than primitive boolean, and use the null case to represent "square not visited yet".   As it was the "square not visited" state was "false".